# Blackberry Access App crash when input type date is clicked in IOS 14 device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-dynamics

Blackberry Access App gets crashes when input type date is clicked in IOS 14 device. I am using latest version of blackberry access (v3.2). This happens only in blackberry access. On safari in IOS 14 device, it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the report.  I'm able to reproduce this as well.  BlackBerry is investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlackBerry is aware of this issue and has implemented a fix.  The fix is present in the beta release of BlackBerry Access.  If you are interested, you can sign up for our beta programs here:  https://ebeta.blackberry.com/enter/

This will be fixed in the next update of BlackBerry Access that will be available soon.

Comment: Thanks. Any update on ETA of next BlackBerry Access IOS Update?

Comment: It is coming out this week.  You may already have it by the time you read this.